# Updating screenshot under "How do I place a bounty?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, help-center

There is an old screenshot under the description of "How do I place a bounty?" in [set bounties privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) help center.
[image]

While the UI is updated to this:
[image]

Comment: Probably deserving of another post, but "You can start a total of 3 simultaneous bounties learn more" isn't a very sentency sentence either...

Comment: This is a massive feature request that will obviously take ~2.5 years for the SO devs to implement, since that's how long it takes for them to (not) change the text of a link.

Comment: @IanKemp More likely the Stack Overflow App will get new features.

Comment: @IanKemp Actually, it only takes 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: If someone is going dispatched on a mission to capture the screenshot of said page, please tell them to turn off ClearType.

Comment: @KodosJohnson - It was 6 to 8 weeks 6 to 8 years ago, have to calculate inflation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the screenshot. The change should be live network-wide.

Thanks for the report!